# IntelliJ 2023.2.5 - how to disable adding serialVersionUID on save

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I have a JPA Entity class that I'm trying to modify, but IntelliJ always automatically adds the following lines to the file:

```
@Serial
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2570912915331392859L;
```

The @Serial annotation isn't found though and it tells me to change the language version, which I can't do. So the project doesn't compile. I tried changing the file in another Editor so the property doesn't get added automatically, but I still get the error "Symbol not found".

I couldn't find any setting to disable this. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by, "can't do"? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html

Comment: quote: but I still get the error "Symbol not found". Can you share a screenshot of the problem?